# Bash Script for loop?

Tags: shell, sh

This is a script that is in a question from a previous exam, I am confused as to why I is equal to 6 and J is equal to nine. Could somebody please elaborate?

Below is a small bash script. What is the output of the final echo
statement? Show your working.

```
 #!/bin/sh
i=0
for a in 9 8 7 6 5 4
do
j=1
for b in 1 2 3 4
do
let "j+=2"
done
let "i+=1"
done
echo "i=$i j=$j"
```

Comment: also show your attempts, please!

Comment: Post your `code` right here, a link is not a good idea.

Comment: Why don't you rewrite that for us? I'm sorry, but I'm using text browser and can't open images...

Comment: Its all normal to me . Correctly I is 6 and J is 9 at the end. What did you expect? What is not clear to you? Run this script with set -x in bash.

Comment: There! I know the answer is 6 and 9 but I'm asking why is it 6 and 9?

Comment: Loops 6 times for `i+=1` and 4 for `j+=2`, `i` starts on 0 so ends up on 6, `j` starts on 1 so is ends up on 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write out the code;

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
for a in 9 8 7 6 5 4   # <-  i gets incremented by 1 for each "step" here.
do 
    j=1
    for b in 1 2 3 4   # <-  j gets incremented by 2 for each "step" here.
    do 
        let "j+=2"     # <-  this is where j get incremented
    done
    let "i+=1"         # <-  this is where i get incremented
done
echo "i=$i j=$j"
```

Therefore,

- j has a starting value of 1, and get incremented by +2 (4 times) = 9
- i has a starting value of 0, and get incremented by +1 (6 times) = 6

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Comment: @MShaw no problem.  Can i suggest you read the asking questions guide. https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking - StackOverflow isn't a forum to post your homework for others to solve - however in this case there were a couple things I liked about your example that would have helped me when I started.